# is it possible to trigger a chrome extention to pop up based on the url visited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension which I want the user to install but keep hidden until the user visits a selected site. When the extention recognizes the url I want it to pop up automatically.

I've set the browser actions and the content scripts and I'm able to trigger an alert on reloading the site with the matching url but I'm hoping to open it automatically when it recognizes the url. Is that possible?

````
  "name": "Chrome Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chrome Extension",
  "permissions": ["notifications", "activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo.png",
    "48": "logo.png",
    "128": "logo.png"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'some-key'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.somesite.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```
````

Comment: A `browser_action` popup can't open automatically. But you can add a standard DOM element in the page itself on the matching URL (using your content script). It can be also an iframe that points to an html file in your extension where you can show a complex UI (look for examples/tutorials that use "web_accessible_resources").

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I recently managed to place a div so I started thinking about an iframe.